# Redis Geoadd is not storing the exact latitude and longitude input as per the user

Tags: redis

While storing lat lon into redis using **geoadd** command, and when I retrieve is using **geopos** my lat lon gets altered. Why does this happen and is there a way to prevent it from happening so that my co-ordinates does not change?
[image: Support Image: Input Coordinates 39.147526478, -84.245874125 and Output 39.14752453565597534, -84.24587448225018704]

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen

Because Redis encode coordinate into a GEOHASH, and save it as a 52bits number. This is memory efficient, but will lose precision. When you fetch the coordinate back, i.e. Redis decode GEOHASH into coordinate, you'll get different longitude and latitude.

> is there a way to prevent it from happening so that my co-ordinates does not change?

You have to store the coordinate separately. Say, use a hash with member name as field, and coordinate as value.

Comment: Can u also address to this ques please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750951/redis-georadius-function-returns-co-ordinates-out-of-the-radius-of-search